# Restoring EFI boot partition

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, uefi, boot-loader

I've been getting back into Linux and am in need of some help.
I have had a few unsucessful attempts at installing Arch as a dual boot along with my Win 10 installation. I think I have finally got it down now, though. However, I am left with a mess of an EFI partition as result of the multiple installations and bootloaders (grub, rEFInd).

How do I go about deleting all traces of my previous installation attempts, restoring the EFI partition to its factory setting - i.e., only having the windows boot loader on it? I would like to do that, and then reinstall arch with grub as the bootloader.

I managed to remove the rEFInd bootloader from the nvram using efibootmgr, but I can't get grub to work still. I would just like a clean start and try again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The EFI partition is a regular FAT32 partition: if Arch does not mount it by default, just mount it (anywhere). There should be an `EFI` directory at the root of that partition: all the EFI bootloaders are in there, in directories named by vendor or OS.
(Note: as the FAT32 is case-insensitive but preserves the case of filenames, capitalization of file and directory names may vary.)

Just delete any `EFI/refind`, `EFI/arch` and whatever directories, but leave the `EFI/Microsoft` directory as-is.

There may also be a `EFI/BOOT`directory, which contains the fallback bootloader (`EFI/BOOT/boot64.efi` on x86_64 systems; on other architectures the name will be different). Windows will typically install a copy of its `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. This allows Windows to boot even if the corresponding NVRAM boot entry is lost.

If there is no applicable NVRAM boot entry, and/or you use firmware boot menus to specify "boot from *this* disk in UEFI style" without explicitly specifying the name of the bootloader `.efi` file, the fallback bootloader file is what the firmware will attempt to load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently, my EFI partition looks like so: `1a9a773e25774d3ab2dd1bda5fcc7203 (folder);
BOOTNXT;
Boot (folder);
EFI (folder);
System Volume Information (folder);
bootmgr;
initramfs-linux-fallback.img;
initramfs-linux.img;
intel-ucode.img;
loader (folder);
vmlinuz-linux`

And further, my EFI folder within looks like so:`Boot, Linux, Microsoft, systemd, tools` Where tools and Linux are unpopulated.

What exectly do I need to remove to delete traces of any boot-loaders, so that the windows one will kick back into action? Thanks!

Comment: Default boot is set in UEFI. You should be able to use efibootmgr `man efibootmgr` to set boot order with -o parameter or just in your UEFI change to have Windows as default or first in boot order. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr  To also delete UEFI boot entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: You can delete the folders `1a9a773e25774d3ab2dd1bda5fcc7203`, `loader`, and the EFI subfolders `Linux` and `systemd`, and files `BOOTNXT`, `bootmgr`, `initramfs-*.img`, `intel-ucode.img`, `vmlinuz-linux`. You should also use the `efibootmgr` command to remove any NVRAM boot variables referring to Arch, if any remain.